# Combine diffuse map and lightmap into one texture file

Tags: unity, textures, lighting, lightmap

Working with Unity, I'd like to do some more memory optimization. Currently, my 3D models have a diffuse texture and a lightmap, both at the same resolution and compression.

I was wondering if there was a way (possibly via Photoshop) by which I can "bake" the lightmap into the diffuse texture to produce the same effect as in-engine.

Thanks!